# Get a invalid syntax when i do int('0b10101010',2)

Tags: python

Just started python and need to do binary to denary (vice versa) but get invalid syntax for int(.

Comment: Works for me. Did you just enter `int('0b10101010',2)` or is there some more code?

Comment: Are you running this from console? Post the whole program and the command you use to run it

Comment: `int('10101010', 2)` works for me (without the `0b`).  What version of python are you using?

Comment: Invalid syntax suggests an error in the code around this line, not this statement as a problem.  A missing colon, an extra or missing parenthesis, bracket, or brace, etc.  The int function obviously works.

Answer (score 2):

That's weird, this works fine:

```
int('0b10101010', 2)
=> 170
```

And so does this:

```
bin(170)
=> '0b10101010'
```